# Where can I buy this doorbell button?

Tags: doorbell

See attached picture. I am not sure if the title is correct. The door bell button (the plastic cover area) broke. Can anyone tell where can I buy this exact doorbell? [image]

Comment: i'm looking for the same doorbell as i have the same problem with a hole in the button. Were you able to find this button or a replacement with the same screw hole length?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would doubt it that you will find the exact replacement.

All doorbells that I am aware of, are wired pretty much the same, 2 wires, doesn't matter which screw it goes to. You will be able to find a doorbell that may fit the same drilled holes, that chance is better than finding the exact same doorbell.

Any big box store, or local hardware store will have a selection in stock.

Comment: Just went to Home depot but they did not have the same size meaning from 1 screw area to last screw area is 5". I may need to find it online. Thanks Jack for the valuable info. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know where you live of course but I used to live in a city that had an architectural salvage place where you could go browse and find old things for your house.  I found an old window sash and thus saved myself the expense of having one custom made.

It might be worth a search online to find one nearest you.  These tend to be places where a lot of browsing is required.  You could very well need to sift through many boxes of old parts for hours to find the right thing.  Still, it's one option.