# Trying to find 5.5" surface mount doorbell button

Tags: doorbell

I really like my doorbell and the plastic push button is broken thus not working. It came with the home when we bought the house from the builder. Now it's hard to find builder materials. It's 5.5" height and 1.2" width. Kinda antique brass gold type finish. I did lots of googling but not able to find. Picture is attached if anyone can help me find this price. I appreciate it.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Extremely relevant: [Where can I buy THIS doorbell?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/61640/where-can-i-buy-this-doorbell-button?rq=1)

Comment: Nice catch @Mazura

Comment: Note to @westin-home  Close is because this is an EXACT duplicate of the question Mazura linked to.

Comment: @ChrisCudmore I thought so too. Woot, my first likely-to-happen close vote ;)

Answer (score 2):

Remove the unit and look for manufacturer's marks on the back side. That would be the only chance to finde an exact replacement.

I would probably buy a cheap doorbell button unit and remove the switch assembly for use in your nice housing. You may need to improvise or alter a bit to make it work.

[image]

Comment: Excellent idea. Will it white plastic button fit from new unit to old? Also I look at the back of the bell and it's plain, no writing at all. Nothing at all.

Comment: There are just a few domestic manufacturers of doorbell hardware, so it used to be easy to find parts that fit each other. With imported stuff flooding the market that has changed. You might get lucky and find a button that fits, or you can insert a plate to take up the space if the button is a bit smaller.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Houseofantiquehardware.com. They have similar size and style antique looking doorbells.

Comment: None of [those](http://search.houseofantiquehardware.com/search/keywords-doorbell--res_per_page-100--sc-15) look big enough.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @Jimmy Fix-it has a lot of merit. But if.....

[image]

...this is a part made of two separate sub assemblies it may give you some more options to use in replacing the switch internals.

Comment: The metal part is one whole body.